# C++ Friend function of nested class in class template

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, friend-function

I'm having the following problem. The code below runs fine on gdb online,
however locally compiling like this:

> /.../g++ -std=c++17 -g -O3
>   /.../Test.cpp -o
>   /.../Test

produces:

> error:
>   'privateMember' is a private member of '`Foo<int>::Nested`'

I also tried with VS2019 - same effect as g++ (which is really a clang:
*Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)*).

**What fixes this issue is:** changing call (comment "//2")

```
make(...) -> make<int>(...)
```

**or**

removing line with comment "//1".

The fixes are independent from each other - **only one needs to be applied**.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
typename Foo<T>::Nested make(T&& t);

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    class Nested
    {
        int privateMember{5};
        friend Nested make<T>(T&& e);
    };

    Nested k; //1
};

template <typename T>
typename Foo<T>::Nested make(T&& t)
{
    typename Foo<T>::Nested nested{}; 
    std::cout<<nested.privateMember<<std::endl;
    return nested;
}

int main() {
    auto i = make(1); //2
    return 0; }
```

**Can somebody explain to me what is happening here?** Why the code runs fine on gbd online and not with g++, also why the changes (1, 2) help?

Comment: msvc does not seem to complain about the private member, but a missing overload. Is your `g++` really clang? Can you add the output of `g++ --version`? gcc compiles this fine, no matter what version I choose. See https://godbolt.org/z/d3QGKf

Comment: GCC 9.2 does not complain about this code...

Comment: @uneven_mark 
correct - this is the error message I'm getting as well with mdvc.
EDIT: 
my g++ indeed is a clang:

'Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)'

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel

I edited my post, my g++ is actually a clang compiler.

Comment: Set up working, non-working cases here: https://godbolt.org/z/m5YfvF . So weird that explicitly specifying the template fixes it. I know it's never a compiler bug, but it sure feels like a compiler bug